# How to replace labels/entries in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def stand():
    e1 = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    e1.grid(row =6, column=3)
    e2 = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    e2.grid(row =7, column=3)
    e3 = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    e3.grid(row =8, column=3)
    e4 = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    e4.grid(row =9, column=3)
    e5 = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    e5.grid(row = 10, column = 3)
    e6 = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    e6.grid(row=11, column = 3)
    p1 = Tkinter.Label (main_window)
    p1.grid(row = 6, column =2)
    p2 = Tkinter.Label (main_window)
    p2.grid(row =7, column =2)
    p3 = Tkinter.Label (main_window)
    p3.grid(row = 8, column =2)
    p4 = Tkinter.Label (main_window)
    p4.grid(row =9 , column =2)
    p5 = Tkinter.Label (main_window)
    p5.grid(row =10 , column =2)
    p6 = Tkinter.Label (main_window)
    p6.grid(row =11 , column =2)
```

I need to remove these and replace them with different entries/labels by pressing a button which deletes the entries/labels that were there and puts up new ones. I've tried everything, but can't find a solution:

```
NameError: global name 'e1' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where does the NameError come from? And what have you tried? Have you done event bindings?

Comment: You don't really need all 6 labels and six entries to duplicate your error, do you? Also, you say you've "tried everything" -- what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the problem in the error message: the interpreter thinks that `e1` is a global name (along with the other widgets), but you defined it within `stand()` in a local scope, so other parts of your program don't know about it. There are multiple solutions to this. One solution is to make it global:

```
e1 = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
def stand():
    global e1
    e1.grid(row =6, column=3)
```

I don't really like doing that. Another solution is to move to an object-oriented approach:

```
class App(object):
    ...
    def stand():
        self.e1 = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
        self.e1.grid(row =6, column=3)

    def access():
        print(self.e1) # can access it
```

Another solution is to pass the widgets as arguments to other functions:

```
def stand():
    self.e1 = Tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    self.e1.grid(row =6, column=3)

def access(widget):
    print(widget)
```

Finally, you should reconfigure widgets by reconfiguring them, not by deleting them and creating new ones:

```
e1.config(width=30)
p1.config(text="New Text")
```